# How do I set the item layout for a Spinner with DataBinding?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-databinding

When attempting to use DataBinding on a Spinner, I am able to get it to show and select items by setting the xml as such:

```
<layout xmlns="blahblahblah">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="myItemList"
            type="java.util.List&lt;myItem>" />
    </data>
</layout>
<LinearLayout>
    <Spinner
        android:entries="@{myItemList}"
        tools:listitem="@layout/my_spinner_items_layout" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I then have `my_spinner_items_layout`with multiple DataBound Views, but I can't seem to find any way to set the Spinner to use the layout I provided; it defaults to the default `ArrayAdapter`, which only has a single `TextView` set to read a `name` value (the `tools:listitem` seems to be only used in the designer in Android Studio).

Even if I try to use

```
myViewBinding.mySpinner.setAdapter(new MySpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.my_spinner_items_layout, myItemList));
```

as I did without DataBinding, none of my functions in my custom adapter get called (except for the constructor, obviously).

How am I supposed to specify a custom layout for a Spinner with DataBinding?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use bindinAdapters and with data binding you can provide powerful functions like this:

```
    @BindingAdapter("entries")
    fun Spinner.setEntries(entries: List<Any>?) {
        setSpinnerEntries(entries)
    }
```

It can be a Util class (SpinnerUtils)

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/item_quantity_spinner"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:entries="@{myItemList}" />
```

References:

- [Binding Adapters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters)
- [Spinner with Data Binding](https://medium.com/fueled-engineering/binding-spinner-in-android-c5fa8c084480)

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: I guess they need to set a custom row layout for the spinner item, not to set the whole list of the spinner

Comment: It looks like this allows me to set in xml properties I can otherwise only set in Java. Since I can't seem to find a Java function that allows me to set the item layout, this leaves me right back where I started. Other than that, this answer seems to only be showing me a different way to do something that I am already doing successfully.